# If $A,B$ are Hermitian and $[ A, B ] = iC$, how to prove that $C$ is also Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I started by taking the conjugate transpose of both sides and end up with:

$$(AB - BA)^t =  (AB)^t - (BA)^t = A^t B^t - B^t A^t = - ([B,A])^t$$

and this equals $$-iC^t$$ where I'm using $\ {}^t \ $ to symbolize conjugate transpose.

Is this accurate? From here, I'm not really sure where to go to prove $C$ is hermitian.

I am in an introductory Quantum class and a lot of this math is going over my head (I've never really dealt with matrices until now), so detailed explanations would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: And i know that $-iC^t = -iC$

Comment: If you know $-iC^\dagger = -iC$ then just divide by $-i$ and you've got it, or did I miss something?  Cheers!

Comment: It's also true that $(-iC)^\dagger = iC^\dagger$, always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $A$ and $B$ are hermitian:

$A^\dagger = A, \tag 1$

$B^\dagger = B; \tag 2$

then

$[A, B]^\dagger = (AB - BA)^\dagger = (AB)^\dagger - (BA)^\dagger$
$= B^\dagger A^\dagger - A^\dagger B^\dagger = BA - AB = -[A, B]; \tag 3$

that is, $[A, B]$ is skew-hermitian; thus if we set

$iC^\dagger = -[A, B]^\dagger = [A, B], \tag 4$

then $iC^\dagger$ is also skew.  We now observe that an operator $D$ is skew if and only if $iD$ is hermitian, since

$D^\dagger = - D \Longrightarrow (iD)^\dagger =-iD^\dagger = iD, \tag 5$

and

$(iD)^\dagger = iD \Longrightarrow -iD^\dagger = iD \Longrightarrow D^\dagger = -D; \tag 6$

in the light of (5)-(6) we conclude that $C^\dagger$ is hermitian, since

$i(iC^\dagger) = -C^\dagger, \tag 7$

and $-C^\dagger$ is hermitian if and only if the same holds for $C^\dagger$, and hence for $C$ since

$C = (C^\dagger)^\dagger = C^\dagger. \tag 8$

Comment: Haven't you already proven it in the line after "thus if we set"? This line shows that $iC^\dagger = [A,B] = iC$.

Comment: @Winther:  yes, but I thought further expansion on this point might clarify for the OP.  By the way, I observe you have "cosmological engagements", as do I.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! This makes more sense, I forgot A and B were also hermitian in this problem. I appreciate the additional elaboration.

Comment: @ZacharyC:  you are more than welcome, sir!  Glad to help out.  Cheers!

Comment: @ZacharyC:  you can always "accept" the answer if you really find it helpful. Cheers!

Comment: How much time did I take to understand the switches :O) to prove the Heisemberg's uncertainty principle where $C=\hbar$ is hermitian.